# issue in redirecting 2 domains in one server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 domains and both are set on one server and when you open each of them , the same website from the same server opens . now i want to redirect one of them to another . for example I have `www.first.com` and `www.second.com` both on one server , and I want my `www.first.com` to be redirected to `www.second.com` . Obviously I cannot make an index to do the redirect because both are on one server so I need another way like creating an htaccess file or something like this .
( I have already tried `redirect 301` and `redirect 302` in htaccess but didn't work )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?first\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.second.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: This rule definitely works. First Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?